# Is it okay to change a key window?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I create a `UIWindow` and make it key and visible in `didFinishLaunching` and later create another `UIWindow` and also make it key and visible. I expect the first window to be abandoned and released from the memory and the second – to be shown. But as I see in the debugger (**Debug View Hierarchy**), they both are in the hierarchy.

Is it normal?

**UPDATE**

The question is not why both objects are in the memory. I'd like to know why both of them are in the view hierarchy? And how can I remove one of them from there?

*Note: Key windows don't have superviews, so I can't do that by simply calling `removeFromSuperview`.*

[image]

Comment: You remove a window by either removing all references it so that it gets deallocated or making it hidden.

Comment: @dan it's possible that I still have a strong reference somewhere. But I also suspect that the first window gets captured by the hierarchy itself. Like it happens with a view when you add it to the view hierarchy. Don't you think it's a case?

Comment: No, views in the view hierarchy are retained because their superview is retaining them.  A window with no superview will not be retained by the view hierarchy.

Comment: @dan hm, that's getting interesting :) but something "knows" top level windows, meaning they might be stored in an array or other collection. If it's really an array then windows are retained for sure. Doesn't it make sense?

Comment: They are stored in an array but it's an array that doesn't retain its objects.

Comment: @dan the only array that doesn't retain objects is `NSPointerArray`. But how do you know? Have you read about it in the Apple's docs?

Comment: You can create a `CFArray` that doesn't retain its objects.  I know from looking at the UIKit code with a disassembler.

Answer (score 0):

If your `AppDelegate` retain first window, it'll never release. And, of course, you can set any created window as key and visible. The `makeKeyAndVisible` method makes a window key and moves it in front of any other windows with same level.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I don't keep a strong reference to the first window in the app delegate (maybe, though I do have it somewhere else...). But question is not about this, sorry for not making it enough clear. I updated the question. Please take a look.